# A letter sequence with curious repetitions

Tags: knowledge, pattern, lateral-thinking, letter-sequence

There was a *time* when I *created* some letter series puzzles. This one is an *old* one. Replace the question marks.

P, Ca, ?, ?, O, Ca, P, Ca, ?, ?, ?, Ca

Hints(1-3):  I will reveal three question marks. Not in order.

Hint 1:

> O

Hint 2:

> Si

Hint 3:

> Si

Hint 4:

> ?~6

Hint 5:

> But there was no *bicycle* at that time

Hint 6:

> In the meanwhile my puzzles became more *diverse*

Comment: I see a number of chemical elements.

Comment: Can you give a small hint?

Comment: @archipelago, Could you please use the "@" sign before an username in comments?

Comment: Before starting real hints here are some "sub-hints": The most @Nick could see is symbols (of chemical elements.) No prime numbers will be involved in this puzzle. After somebody removed the lateral thinking tag, I put it back.

Comment: P, Ca, O, P, O, Ca, P, Ca, O, O, P, Ca

Comment: no, this is incorrect

Comment: P, Ca, O, P, O, Ca, P, Ca, O, P, O, Ca

Comment: Is the chemical elements somehow linked to the 12 signs of the zodiac?

Comment: Nothing is linked to the zodiac.

Comment: Clearly you are hinting that there is some history-related connection to this puzzle, but I'm yet to spot what that is... Is it a closed sequence (i.e. 12 terms and no more) or can it theoretically be extended still further? Thanks.

Comment: Good question! I created this sequence. It cannot be extended. (It's like a copyright, more or less :) )

Comment: Does rot13(gur ahzore bs grezf) have something to do with a rot13(pybpx) or a rot13(pnyraqne)?

Comment: @shoover no, it doesn't

Answer (score 2):

This may be a stretch as this seems mostly irrespective of the ordering of the sequence.

> P, Ca, C, Si, O, Ca, P, Ca, Si, O, C, Ca

Explanation:

> The first five elements are the constituent parts of the chemical reaction of Calcium Phosphate, Carbon Coke, and Silicon Dioxide: P, Ca, C, Si, O. The latter seven elements give the products (and this is where it definitely disregards the ordering in the reaction): Ca, P, Ca, Si, O, C, Ca.  I think the three occurrences of Ca in the second subsequence is indicative of the yield including three Calcium Silicates. Link to a page with the reaction: https://chemiday.com/en/reaction/3-1-0-794

Comment: no, but upvoted for giving insight to some chemistry

Answer (score 0):

Here’s my answer:

> P, Ca, O, Si, O, Ca, P, Ca, O, Si, 0, Ca

This is the pattern as it can be formed as **you** said you have revealed three answers to replace the question mark.

Comment: Technically this is just *one* of the possible patterns that can be formed by adding the three hinted symbols (since there are still two unknowns, and since these unknowns could be paired in the same position within the two halves, they could be *any* pair of matching symbols - if indeed both halves should match at all). So why this *particular* pattern, please? Thanks :)